# can i stop view or scroll timeline animation when scrolling up?

Tags: css, css-animations, timeline

i am learning css timeline animations with view() and scroll(). it all works great but one issue: unlike when using javascript observation intersection, i cannot seem to stop the animation while scrolling up. so for example is i have this code:

```
.do-fade{
animation: fade-in 350ms linear forwards;
animation-timeline: view(block);
animation-range: 100px 300px;
}

@keyframes fade-in{
 from{opacity:0}
 to{opacity:1}
}
```

the fade-in animation will be implemented both on the way down and up. what is i want it to only be implemented when scrolling down a page?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: is this better?

Comment: Nope... a working demo is required.